# CSS Width Being Ignored

Tags: css

Please can someone advise why the width, and padding in the below code is being ignored?

```
.chartbox {
    display: none;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 50;
    width: 40;
}
```

The website is http://www.jameswinfield.co.uk/v2.html#, and it should happen when clicking the 'chart' tab on the top-left menu.

Thanks
James

Comment: padding: 50px; width: 40px;

Comment: You haven't specified any units. 40 what? Pixels, percent, ems?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing units, for example px, em, %.
Example:

```
.chartbox {
    display: none;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Also, you should remove the display:none to display the item on the browser.

Comment: Oh gosh that really was dumb.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing length [units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Units). You need to specify `px`, `em`, `%`, or any one of the types of available units in CSS.

```
.chartbox {
    padding: 50px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Documentation

- [Length#Units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Units)

Comment: Oh gosh that really was dumb.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Any measurement properties like `height`, `width`, `padding`, `margin`  should be defined in `px` or `cm` or `em` or `%`.

```
.chartbox {
    display: none;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh gosh that really was dumb.  Thanks very much.